# allow UTF-8 encoded filenames on (file-)webserver?

Tags: url, encoding, utf-8, download, cp1252

I am hosting a small fileserver, where users can upload documents from all around the world.

Due to problems in encoding (see [otherquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067713/how-to-url-encode-filenames-containing-special-utf-8-or-cp1252-characters)), I am asking myself if I should disallow users to upload (and on the other hand download) files not supported by CP1252 charset?

or otherwise; is it senseful to allow users upload documents with arabian or chinese letters in their filenames?

PS: they download the same file some time later (and it should have the same filename as uploaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be storing the files on disk using a randomly generated name, or let the file name be based on a hash of the file contents (good for deduplicating storage as well). You can save the original file name as meta data in a database together with all other meta data about the file (who uploaded it and things like that). Then you serve the file again using a PHP script which sets the original file name from the database in an HTTP header. This way you:

- don't need to worry about file name sanitisation or duplication
- file system encoding issues
- storage duplication (if using a hash)

Comment: Thanks for these hints, one thing must work: to access die file directly by link. so if a user gets a url to the file, the php connects everytime to the db? doesn't this take too much time when he has e.g. 10 files to open? do you have a ready php script for that?

Comment: Database access should in no way be a limiting factor here if done decently. See http://php.net/readfile. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476 if you want pretty links. Also ideally see https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/.

Comment: hmmm; do you have a reference-script for that?